# Algorithm to Determine String Placement?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have two sets of strings - about 5000 strings in each group - (more specifically, sequences only consisting of ACTG), and they are split into two groups based on some other data. Every single string is of equal length, and efficiency doesn't matter. Given a certain sequence, I want to be able to determine which category that string will fall in*. What algorithms should I use to do this?

*Based purely on the previous data in the groups.

A small example:

Group 1: AATTGG
Group 2: ATCCGC

Then if I had the string CCGTCC, it would go to group 2, because group 2 has sequences with more C's, compared to group 1, which prefers doubles of A, T, and G.

Comment: The question, as posed, is much too vague to be answerable. (Though this might be relevant: https://matthewayne.com/images/machine-learning.gif :))

Comment: How about some examples?

Comment: It kinda sounds like you are after a machine learning classification problem. But I can't tell from what's been written.

Comment: I tried using perceptron, but I'm not sure how I would even sort the data. Because String->number is where I am stuck. How would I calculate a number based off a string?

Comment: you don´t need a number, you need a vector of numbers and it could be A = 0, C = 1, T = 2 and G = 3

Comment: I already  assigned weights to each letter.

Comment: Your question doesn't really sound Python-related to me...asking for a algorithm is a generic thing...

Comment: This is not weights, it is the encoding. Still, it is unclear what you already did and what you want

Comment: essentially, I just want an algorithm (preferably) in python, that accomplishes what is specified above. I have essentially done nothing (what I have done just doesn't work, and I'm not sure perceptron should even be used).

Comment: This is a straightforward ML classification problem.  There are many available algorithms; we need you to work through the available information with respect to your data, and come back with a specific question.  Given only two observations, there's no way we could suggest particular algorithms, even if that were within scope for Stack Overflow.  Start with a search for "Machine learning classification" and see what fits your data.

Comment: The problem is that "what you specified above" is not sufficient. You want to categorize your strings based on previous data in the groups. What previous data? Do you have some examples of the criteria you will use?

Comment: sorry. I just wasn't sure for what I wanted to look for in each string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is underdetermined.  And there is no good answer.  But you're still being asked to do it.  That's real life.

So you have a choice.  Learn a lot about machine learning.  That will let you do something smart.  Or do the stupidest thing that could possibly work and then see if you like the results.

Based on the description of your problem, I would suggest the following approach.  Construct "predictors" out of current data that predict which character should appear next.  Take the one whose predictors produce the best result.

So what kind of predictors?  I would suggest using [ngrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) with Laplace smoothing (add one of each unseen answer).  That's simple to implement, and in practice works fairly well with DNA data.  Then you can do something like have a 0-gram (just letter frequency), 1-gram (based on the previous letter), 2-gram (previous 2 letters) and 3-gram.

For each predictor, and each letter that can be predicted, you can construct the log of the likelihood that that predictor gives to that letter.  Add the logs, and the one at the end with the best likelihood is the winner.  (Adding logs is mathematically equivalent to multiplying probabilities, but avoids running out of the range of floating point.)

Your example is too small to show the real power of the technique.  There isn't enough data for the 1-gram, 2-gram and 3-gram to have been trained at all.  (For the 1-grams, no sequence of XY, appeared twice, so because Laplace smoothing, all answers are considered equally likely after any observed X.  Replace X with XY and XYZ for 2-grams and 3-grams.)

However the 0-gram will give group 1 2/7 likelihood to A, G and T, but only 1/7 to C.  (The 7'th character is the fake observation of `C` which did not actually appear in the string - that's Laplace smoothing.)  For the test string this gives `2*log(2/7) + 4* log(1/7) = -10.289166533212`.  By contrast gives group 2 1/6 likelihood to A, G and T, but 1/2 to C.  This gives `2*log(1/6) + 4*log(1/2) = -6.35610766069589`  Since group 2's predictor did better, assign it to group 2.

Please note, this technique got the result that you expected for the reasoning that you wished to apply.  Group 2 had more Cs, so the new string with lots of Cs gets assigned to group 2.  And if you had more data and your described patterns continued to hold, group 1 would get things with doubles of A, G and T.

Please also note, given a lot of strings, this technique will pick up on patterns that can be described by the frequency of individual letters and of short runs.  But it will not pick up on other kinds of patterns that might exist.  For example if the starting character was a really strong signal for group 1 vs group 2, you wouldn't notice.  Other techniques could.

Here is code for this technique:

```
import math
n_limit = 4

def make_predictor (strings):
    freq_dict = {}
    for string in strings:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            for j in range(n_limit): # 0..3
                if j <= i:
                    substr = string[i-j:i]
                    if substr not in freq_dict:
                        freq_dict[substr] = {}
                    freq = freq_dict[substr]
                    char = string[i]
                    if char not in freq:
                        freq[char] = 1.0
                    else:
                        freq[char] = freq[char] + 1.0

    # Smoothing and precalculation of logs.
    predict_dict = {}
    for substr, freq in freq_dict.iteritems():
        for char in 'ACGT':
            if char not in freq:
                freq[char] = 1.0
        total = sum(freq.values())
        predict = {}
        for char, f in freq.iteritems():
            predict[char] = math.log(f / total)
        predict_dict[substr] = predict

    return predict_dict

def run_predictor (predict_dict, string):
    answer = 0.0
    empty_predict = math.log(0.25) # 4 values, equally likely.
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(n_limit):
            if j <= i:
                substr = string[i-j:i]
                if substr not in predict_dict:
                    answer = answer + empty_predict
                else:
                    answer = answer + predict_dict[substr][string[i]]
    return answer

def classify (p1, p2, string):
    if run_predictor(p1, string) < run_predictor(p2, string):
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

predictor1 = make_predictor(['AATTGG'])
predictor2 = make_predictor(['ATCCGC'])

print(classify(predictor1, predictor2, 'CCGTCC'))
```

Now to test it, I would suggest randomly splitting your groups into groups 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B.  If predictors generated from 1A and 2A can successfully classify things from 1B and 2B into groups 1 and 2, then the technique probably works well enough with your data to be useful.

Comment: @JerryQian I added code, clarified my explanation, explained what its shortcomings are and offered advice on how to test whether this technique is likely to work well with your data.

Comment: thanks! I am just curious to know where you discovered this algorithm? I think that knowing more algorithms will be beneficial (not just in this field).

Comment: @JerryQian Honestly, already knew about ngrams, and  thought that your description of how you thought about the problem sounded like a fit.  I reminded myself how they work and said, "This should work well enough."

Comment: what does the n_limit do? Sorry for the abundance of questions. :(

Comment: also, p1 and p2 can be the list of all my sequences right?

Comment: @JerryQian `p1` and `p2` should be predictors generated off of your sequences.  What `n_limit` does is control how long of ngrams we consider.  If the limit is 4 then we do 0-grams, 1-grams, 2-grams and 3-grams.  The tradeoff is that longer is slower and takes more memory, but can pick up on more patterns.

Comment: I'm still confused on why you are taking the logs? Could I just multiply the probabilities together, and compare them  as such?